# how do I access the first and last row of an arraylist of arraylist

Tags: java

I was wondering how I could access the first and last row of this 2d arraylist.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> list(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> grid){

    ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++){
        for( int j = 0; j <grid.get(i).size(); j++){
            System.out.print(grid.get(i).get(j) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

this code will print out the entire arraylist. Is there a way to get the first row and last row only

3 4 1 2 8 6

6 1 8 2 7 4

5 4 3 9 9 5

5 9 8 3 2 6

8 7 2 9 6 4

Comment: What values do `i` and `j` have while the first row is being printed? What values do they have while the last row is being printed? You can either add more `print` calls, or use the debugger to answer that question.

Comment: And what do you mean by "get"?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I mean to either print the first row only [3 4 1 2 8 6], or print the last row[8 7 2 9 6 4].

Comment: I just figure out how to print the first row. Any thoughts on how to print just the last row?

Comment: You already know how to get the number of rows. And you know that the final index is one less than that.

Comment: Yes. thank you. that is clear now. I'm thinking i = grid.size() - 1; i < grid.size()< i++.

Answer (score 1):

`grid.get(0)` gives you the first row, and `grid.get(grid.size()-1)` gives you the last row.

If you want to print them out then do this:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> list(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> grid){
ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<>();

int[] firstLastIndices = new int[]{0, grid.size()-1}
for(int i : firstLastIndices){
    for( int j = 0; j <grid.get(i).size(); j++){
        System.out.print(grid.get(i).get(j) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```